# Inflight Window interval in MQTT Paho library

Tags: android, eclipse, mqtt, paho

For QoS 1 in MQTT, publish a message will be like this:

1. PUBLISH message
2. ... some time pass ...
3. Receive PUBACK (acknowledgment that server received the message) OR
   Didn't receive the message in due time, resend message.

What is Paho library default timeout called "Inflight Window" used by library if doesn't receive PUBAKN will send the message again to server.

In MqttConnectOptions class I find:

> The message delivery retry interval is 15 seconds

but I'm not sure if it's the same as what I'm searching about. and if it is how can I change it (customize it)